# More than one function on one variable

Tags: php, sql, str-replace, ucfirst

I want to write something in the database, but before I want to delete all spaces in the string and upper the first letter.

That's how I wanted to do it but it doesnt work :P

```
//INITIALIZATION OF VARIABLE $perfectFirstname 

    $perfectFirstname = str_replace(' ','',$_POST["firstnameInput"]);

//PART OF MY QUERY

    $sql .=     "'".mysql_real_escape_string(ucfirst($perfectFirstname))."', ";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt work? Do you get an error? Is the name never modified... what?

Comment: Get rid of that mysql_real_escape_string! Get rid of the MySQL extension! Start using MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Yes IMO PDO with strict mode is the best .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) for upper case:

```
$your_var = mysql_real_escape_string(ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$_POST["firstnameInput"]))));
```

Comment: I guess it would be better if strtolower() is also used since the question only needs the first letter to be Capital .

Answer (score 0):

how about,

```
$perfectFirstname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST["firstnameInput"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$_POST["firstnameInput"] = 'Billy';

$sql = '';
$sql .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string(ucfirst(str_replace(' ','', $_POST["firstnameInput"])))."', ";

var_dump($sql);


// OR, to reuse, a function like:

function MyEscape ($text) {
  return mysql_real_escape_string(ucfirst(str_replace(' ','', $text)));
}

$sql = '';
$sql .= "'".MyEscape($_POST["firstnameInput"])."', ";
var_dump($sql);

?>
```

Comment: OK, the ucfirst() has to be outside the function (for re-use).